# ng-translate error while running ng serve

Tags: angular, ngx-translate

I working on ngx-translate. Running my implemented code fires the following error on ng serve.

```
rror: node_modules/@ngx-translate/http-loader/lib/http-loader.d.ts:4:22 - error NG6002: Appears in the NgModule.imports of AppModule, but could not be resolved to an NgModule class.       

This likely means that the library (@ngx-translate/http-loader) which declares TranslateHttpLoader has not been processed correctly by ngcc, or is not compatible with Angular Ivy. Check if 
a newer version of the library is available, and update if so. Also consider checking with the library's authors to see if the library is expected to be compatible with Ivy.

4 export declare class TranslateHttpLoader implements TranslateLoader {
```

In node_modules http-loader.d.ts the class TranslateHttpLoader is also underlined.

```
export declare class TranslateHttpLoader implements TranslateLoader {
    private http;
    prefix: string;
    suffix: string;
    constructor(http: HttpClient, prefix?: string, suffix?: string);
    /**
     * Gets the translations from the server
     */
    getTranslation(lang: string): Observable<Object>;
}
```

This is my AppModule:

```
import { HttpClient, HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { TranslateModule, TranslateLoader } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { TranslateHttpLoader } from '@ngx-translate/http-loader';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

export function createTranslateLoader(http: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, './assets/i18n/', '.json');
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    TranslateHttpLoader,
    TranslateModule.forRoot(
      {
        loader: {
          provide: TranslateLoader,
          useFactory: (createTranslateLoader),
          deps: [HttpClient]
        },
        defaultLanguage: 'en'
      }
    ),
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I use:

node: 12.19.0

Angular: 11.2.13

ngx-translate/core: 13.0.0

ngx-translate/http-loader: 6.0.0

What’s the problem, are there any ideas out there?

Comment: Try running command "npm ci"

Comment: Thanks for the comment! But it doesn't fixed this issue.

Comment: Please add your AppModule.ts

Comment: Which version of `ngx-translate` are you using? The error is saying the library might be not compatible with Ivy which is enabled by default in Angular 11.

Comment: Added the version of ngx-translate and AppModule to my question.

Comment: You need to remove `TranslateHttpLoader` from your import array in the module.

Comment: Yes, removing TranslateHTTPLoader fixed the issue. Don't know when and why I added this to the imports array. Please post your answer, I'll sign it as solution!

Comment: @Christoph1972 Glad it helped. Added an answer and please do upvote as well :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remove `TranslateHttpLoader` from your import array of `NgModule`. Maybe you added it by mistake.
Thanks!